# Icons get changed in static declaration in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I have a class AppIcons which consist of a list of icons (IconlyLight) and returns **static List get allIcons** as an icon list to use in a screen where a user can create a category and choose an icon for that category. User can select any icon that is presented in a grid view. I user hive to save these categories user adds. Following is my category model.

```
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class CategoryModel extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  late String label;
  @HiveField(1)
  late DateTime modifiedAt;
  @HiveField(2)
  Color? catColor;
  @HiveField(3)
  IconData? catIcon;

  CategoryModel({
    required this.label,
    required this.modifiedAt,
    required this.catColor,
    required this.catIcon,
  });
}
```

Saving a category is like this.

```
void _createCategory(BuildContext context,
      {String? label, IconData? icon, Color? color}) {
    final categoriesBox = Hive.box<CategoryModel>('categories');
    CategoryModel newCategory = CategoryModel(
      label: label!,
      catIcon: icon!,
      catColor: color!,
      modifiedAt: DateTime.now(),
    );
    categoriesBox.add(newCategory);
    Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
  }
```

Now i fetch these added category as a list like so

```
final categoryBox = Hive.box<CategoryModel>('categories');
    if (categoryBox.values.isNotEmpty) {
      _categoryList = categoryBox.values.toList();
    }

class AppIcons {
  static const activity = IconlyLight.activity;
  static const addUser = IconlyLight.add_user;
  ....
}
static List<IconData> get allIcons => [
        activity,
        addUser,
        ...
];

List<IconData>? _icons;
@override
  void initState() {
     _icons = AppIcons.allIcons;
    super.initState();
  }
```

I do represent these in a more graphical manner ofcourse but i have an issue in keeping the original created category icon for each category. When i restart the app all the icons are changed and every category does not show its originally created icon.

I need some guidance to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: add more code for reproducing the error. AppIcons, the static list, point of accessing the list, etc seems to not be present at the moment.